# How to securely quote an optional flag?

Tags: bash

If `$FOO` is set, I want to run:

```
cd "$OUTPUTDIR" && fpm -s dir -t rpm \
  -a x86_64 \
  --epoch "${PKGEPOCH}" \
  -n "${PACKAGENAME}" \
  --version "${PKGVERSION}" \
  --iteration "${PKGRELEASE}" \
  -C "$OUTPUTDIR/installroot" \
  --description="${PKGDESCRIPTION}" \
  .
```

If `$FOO` is not set, I don't want to include the flag at all.

The program fails if `--description=` (empty).

However, sometimes descriptions include quotes and other special characters so I don't want to do:

```
if [[ -z "PKGDESCRIPTION" ]]; then
    D=--description="${PKGDESCRIPTION}"
fi
cd "$OUTPUTDIR" && fpm -s dir -t rpm \
  -a x86_64 \
  --epoch "${PKGEPOCH}" \
  -n "${PACKAGENAME}" \
  --version "${PKGVERSION}" \
  --iteration "${PKGRELEASE}" \
  -C "$OUTPUTDIR/installroot" \
  $D
  .
```

If I put quotes around `$D` then it becomes an additional (blank) arg.

Is there a way to do this that won't be a security problem if `$PKGDESCRIPTION` includes special chars AND doesn't generate a blank arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PKGDESCRIPTION is the only argument that needs this conditional treatment, you can use an "alternate value" expansion:

```
[...] && fpm -s dir -t rpm \
    [...] \
    ${PKGDESCRIPTION:+ --description="${PKGDESCRIPTION}"} \
    .
```

Explanation: the `:+` means this will expand to nothing at all unless PKGDESCRIPTION is set to a non-null value; if it is set to something non-null, it expands to `--description="${PKGDESCRIPTION}"`, and the double-quotes make it ignore special characters in PKGDESCRIPTION's value. Note that the space in `:+ --` isn't needed, but does no harm and makes it at least slightly easier to read.

BTW, if more than one argument needs this treatment, I'd go with @glenn jackman's approach.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Short and simple.  By the way... I had gotten close to this solution but I had quotes around it which added a null argument.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

Using an array is the only sane way to do this:

```
options=( -a x86_64  -C "$OUTPUTDIR/installroot" )
[[ $PKGEPOCH ]]       && options+=( --epoch "$PGKEPOCH" )
[[ $PACKAGENAME ]]    && options+=( -n "$PACKAGENAME" )
[[ $PKGVERSION ]]     && options+=( --version "$PKGVERSION" )
[[ $PKGRELEASE ]]     && options+=( --iteration "$PKGRELEASE" )
[[ $PKGDESCRIPTION ]] && options+=( --description="$PKGDESCRIPTION" )

cd "$OUTPUTDIR" && fpm -s dir -t rpm "${options[@]}"
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Thanks!  Is  `[[ $VAR ]]` the same as `[[ -z $VAR ]]` ?  Any pros/cons?

Comment: `[[ $VAR ]]` is the same as `[[ -n $VAR ]]` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: Doh!  Yes, I meant -z, not -n.  Thanks!